# Why can't I find this .xaml file?

Tags: wpf

I want to run this program

[This is my app.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKMQD.png)ps://i.stack.imgur.com/HXWct.png

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code and/or error messages (something to read: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2819245), [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [Pictures of exceptions are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your StartupUri in App.xaml should look more like Data_binding/HelloBoundWorldSample.xaml ?